# AF Request gives data corrupted "The given data was not valid JSON." swift 5

Tags: swift5

My AF request is

```
AF.request("https://172.16.3.211/api/login.php?username=\(username)&password=\(password)", method:.get).response { response in
            if response.data != nil
            {
                print(response.data)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(UserLoginResponse.self, from: response.data!)
                    print(response.data)
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
                
            }
            else
            {
                print("Record not found")
            }
        }
```

and my api result is

```
{
code: "200",
msg: "success",
data: [
{
id: "1",
username: "admin",
password: "123456",
fullname: "Json Res",
fcm_token: null,
apartment_no: "10",
cnic_no: "123",
phone_no: "123"
}
]
}
```

my api response is

```
import Foundation


struct UserLoginResponse: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let data: UserLogin
    let msg: String
}
```

and UserLogin is

```
import Foundation


struct UserLogin:     Codable {
    let fullname: String
    let username: String
    let password: String
    
}
```

Comment: The error is related to the server communication. The response is probably HTML . Besides there are two type mismatches in the structs, `code` is `String` and `data` is `[UserLogin]`

Comment: ive changed code to int now

Comment: thankyou that worked adding[] to UserLogin